# Python for loops stops after first iteration

Tags: python, for-loop

I’m having trouble debugging my `get_secondary_connections` function below. For some reason, my `for friend in network[user][‘connections’]` loop always stops at the first value in the list instead of looping through the entire list. I don’t understand why that’s the case. Can someone give me some guidance on this? Thanks so much!

Here’s my network:

```
network = { 

'Freda': {'connections': ['Olive', 'John', 'Debra'], 'favorite games': ['Starfleet Commander', 'Ninja Hamsters', 'Seahorse Adventures']}, 

'Ollie': {'connections': ['Mercedes', 'Freda', 'Bryant'], 'favorite games': ['Call of Arms', 'Dwarves and Swords', 'The Movie: The Game']}, 

'Debra': {'connections': ['Walter', 'Levi', 'Jennie', 'Robin'], 'favorite games': ['Seven Schemers', 'Pirates in Java Island', 'Dwarves and Swords']}, 

'Olive': {'connections': ['John', 'Ollie'], 'favorite games': ['The Legend of Corgi', 'Starfleet Commander']}, 

'Levi': {'connections': ['Ollie', 'John', 'Walter'], 'favorite games': ['The Legend of Corgi', 'Seven Schemers', 'City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma']}, 

'Jennie': {'connections': ['Levi', 'John', 'Freda', 'Robin'], 'favorite games': ['Super Mushroom Man', 'Dinosaur Diner', 'Call of Arms']}, 

'Mercedes': {'connections': ['Walter', 'Robin', 'Bryant'], 'favorite games': ['The Legend of Corgi', 'Pirates in Java Island', 'Seahorse Adventures']}, 

'John': {'connections': ['Bryant', 'Debra', 'Walter'], 'favorite games': ['The Movie: The Game', 'The Legend of Corgi', 'Dinosaur Diner']}, 

'Robin': {'connections': ['Ollie'], 'favorite games': ['Call of Arms', 'Dwarves and Swords']}, 

'Bryant': {'connections': ['Olive', 'Ollie', 'Freda', 'Mercedes'], 'favorite games': ['City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma', 'Super Mushroom Man']},

'Walter': {'connections': ['John', 'Levi', 'Bryant'], 'favorite games': ['Seahorse Adventures', 'Ninja Hamsters', 'Super Mushroom Man']} }
```

And here’s my code:

```
def get_secondary_connections(network, user):
    if user not in network:
        return None
    sec_connections = []
    for friend in network[user]['connections']:
        for connection in network[friend]['connections']:
            if connection not in sec_connections:
                sec_connections.append(connection)
    return sec_connections
```

When I run get_secondary_connections(network, “Mercedes”), I get the following output:

```
[‘John’, ‘Levi’, ‘Bryant’]
```

Which, if you checked back at my network, is only Walter’s list of connections. I’m supposed to get the full list of Mercedes’ secondary connections, that is:

```
[‘John’, ‘Levi’, ‘Bryant’, ‘Ollie’, ‘Olive’, Freda’, ‘Mercedes’]
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Running your code shows me exactly the same as your desired output.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Are you sure the input is correct?

Comment: Thanks guys, I realized there was something wrong with my editor and it wasn't running my code correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I copy-pasted your code and run the program and got the output:

```
['John', 'Levi', 'Bryant', 'Ollie', 'Olive', 'Freda', 'Mercedes']
```

This output is what you wanted, right? There's nothing wrong with your code. If you'd like, this is how the code looks:

```
network = {
'Freda': {'connections': ['Olive', 'John', 'Debra'], 'favorite games': ['Starfleet Commander', 'Ninja Hamsters', 'Seahorse Adventures']},

'Ollie': {'connections': ['Mercedes', 'Freda', 'Bryant'], 'favorite games': ['Call of Arms', 'Dwarves and Swords', 'The Movie: The Game']},

'Debra': {'connections': ['Walter', 'Levi', 'Jennie', 'Robin'], 'favorite games': ['Seven Schemers', 'Pirates in Java Island', 'Dwarves and Swords']},

'Olive': {'connections': ['John', 'Ollie'], 'favorite games': ['The Legend of Corgi', 'Starfleet Commander']},

'Levi': {'connections': ['Ollie', 'John', 'Walter'], 'favorite games': ['The Legend of Corgi', 'Seven Schemers', 'City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma']},

'Jennie': {'connections': ['Levi', 'John', 'Freda', 'Robin'], 'favorite games': ['Super Mushroom Man', 'Dinosaur Diner', 'Call of Arms']},

'Mercedes': {'connections': ['Walter', 'Robin', 'Bryant'], 'favorite games': ['The Legend of Corgi', 'Pirates in Java Island', 'Seahorse Adventures']},

'John': {'connections': ['Bryant', 'Debra', 'Walter'], 'favorite games': ['The Movie: The Game', 'The Legend of Corgi', 'Dinosaur Diner']},

'Robin': {'connections': ['Ollie'], 'favorite games': ['Call of Arms', 'Dwarves and Swords']},

'Bryant': {'connections': ['Olive', 'Ollie', 'Freda', 'Mercedes'], 'favorite games': ['City Comptroller: The Fiscal Dilemma', 'Super Mushroom Man']},

'Walter': {'connections': ['John', 'Levi', 'Bryant'], 'favorite games': ['Seahorse Adventures', 'Ninja Hamsters', 'Super Mushroom Man']} 
}

def get_secondary_connections(network, user):
    if user not in network:
        return None
    sec_connections = []
    for friend in network[user]['connections']:
        for connection in network[friend]['connections']:
            if connection not in sec_connections:
                sec_connections.append(connection)
    return sec_connections

print get_secondary_connections(network, "Mercedes")
```

Comment: You don't provide a solution other than what has been said in the question. A single comment would have been enough.

Comment: I am really sorry. But the button here said 'Post your Answer' and I posted my answer.

Comment: You got it wrong. An answer should adds some new solutions or features which is not contained in the original question.

Comment: I am truly sorry. I did not mean to insult you. You see, I am new to Stack Overflow. I'm just learning to do this stuff :) Also, Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post and you should also not use the comment section for Secondary Discussions. i.e., what we are doing right now is wrong.